# Cant get a response from MySQL using NodeRed function

Tags: mysql, sql, database, node-red

I want to get out put from NodeRed mysql node. I want to send a query to MySQL and receive an output which gives me the size of my database. The name of the database is demoopcua.

Heres an image of the connection :

[image: Image of flow]

Here is what is in my function :

```
msg.topic = "SELECT table_schema AS demoopcua,ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 2) AS `Size (MB)`,FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema;"
```

Here is the flow if you would like to import it :

```
[{"id":"a98232e2.89bb4","type":"tab","label":"Data Storage ","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"f50611a.320baf","type":"mysql","z":"a98232e2.89bb4","mydb":"f1e0508e.13503","name":"db","x":470,"y":360,"wires":[["73e15eff.866b3"]]},{"id":"73e15eff.866b3","type":"debug","z":"a98232e2.89bb4","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":630,"y":360,"wires":[]},{"id":"6936d2d6.33b00c","type":"function","z":"a98232e2.89bb4","name":"","func":"msg.topic = \"SELECT table_schema AS demoopcua,ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 2) AS `Size (MB)`,FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema;\"\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","x":320,"y":360,"wires":[["f50611a.320baf"]]},{"id":"ee29a71.86c0b58","type":"inject","z":"a98232e2.89bb4","name":"","props":[{"p":"payload"},{"p":"topic","v":"","vt":"msg"}],"repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","x":140,"y":360,"wires":[["6936d2d6.33b00c"]]},{"id":"f1e0508e.13503","type":"MySQLdatabase","name":"","host":"127.0.0.1","port":"3306","db":"test dump","tz":"","charset":"UTF8"}]
```

Comment: Without the database schema we can't really help here. Also this is most likely a SQL problem not a Node-RED problem, assuming you are getting no errors back when you submit that query.

Comment: Im not too sure what you mean by database schema. Also, i do receive an error when i run this flow. I get this : `"Error: Invalid property expression: zero-length"`

Comment: Check your single quotes in the SQL query they should probably be ' not `

Comment: I still get the same zero length error :(. i apologize for any misunderstanding. im very new to this and im still learning as i go along.

Comment: The database schema is the table layout https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema

Comment: im still unsure of how to solve this node red issue ;-;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your inject node. You have configured the topic to be set from a none existent (empty) `msg` variable.

[image]

Click the cross at the end of the `msg.topic` line to remove this entry.

Comment: An important point here is that is you had put the mouse over the error it would have shown you which node it has come from

Comment: That solved the zero length error :D but it gave me another error
`"Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema' at line 1"`

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found out how to solve this issue. To solve this issue, place an inject node and copy this MySQL Query into the msg.topic.

`SELECT table_schema "your database name here", sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 1024 "Data Base Size in MB" FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema ;`

[image]